# Forward Angular 4 app static assets to a /PORT path instead of main domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, pm2

We have an [Angular 4](https://angular.io/) app which is [exposed](https://medium.com/defmethod-works/building-an-express-node-js-app-with-angular-2-and-the-twitter-api-4eebd06fecff) from inside a [Node](https://nodejs.org/) +
 [Express](https://expressjs.com/) app, hence is started as a normal node app. Somewhat like: `node index.js`

This works fantastic when done on local machine. The angular app gets served from the `/client` directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
```

When this project is deployed to some server, [express perfectly responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528039/angular-4-components-are-not-found-404s-with-pm2-deployment-and-nginx-reverse#comment76049156_44528039) with `client/index.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 4 app</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
    <my-app>
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </my-app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/jquery.connectingLine.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The template of the app is taken from [here](https://github.com/gopinav/Angular-2-Tutorials) based on [these tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg5gEu2KF4sbGvpUqMRSBSW).

**Port forwarding:**

The [nginx](https://nginx.org/) is there to do the reverse proxy with the following rules:

- Any request like [appUrl/port](http://appUrl/port) shall internally be routed to [localhost:port](http://appUrl:port)
- On the https://angular4AppDomain.com server - the `Angular4AndNodeApp` app is started at `PORT 8080` (ref **Deployment process:** point 7)
- Hence requests to [https://angular4AppDomain.com/8080/](https://angular4AppDomain.com/PORT/) are internally **PORT FORWARDED** to [https://localhost:8080/](https://localhost:PORT/)

**Debugging information:**

- When we hit [https://angular4AppDomain.com/8080/](https://angular4AppDomain.com/PORT/), it hits to node server and returns `client/index.html` file - **200 OK**
- `client/index.html` file has `<script>` & `<link>` tags which are wrongly hitting to https://angular4AppDomain.com/ instead of [https://angular4AppDomain.com/8080/](https://angular4AppDomain.com/PORT/) - **404 Not found**

[**Deployment process:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528039/angular-4-components-are-not-found-404s-with-pm2-deployment#comment76048255_44528039)

1. The app is loaded on the server using [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
2. Go app directory `cd app`
3. Go to Angular 2 app directory `cd client`
4. Install Angular 2 dependencies `npm i`
5. Compile the Angular 2 project `npm run tsc:w`
6. Go back to app directory `cd ..`
7. Run command `PORT=8080 pm2 start index.js --name=Angular4AndNodeApp`

As suggested, [`<base href="/">` is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528039/angular-4-components-are-not-found-404s-with-pm2-deployment#comment76048743_44528039) and we're accessing the [virtual path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528039/angular-4-components-are-not-found-404s-with-pm2-deployment?noredirect=1#comment76048792_44528039). However, instead of hitting http://example.com/someapp/index.html, we're hitting http://example.com/PORT/index.html.

In this project, all the Angular 4 components are **404**s.

<strike>This may be happening probably because the app is not getting compiled properly.</strike>

How do we make sure that all these static assets are has `<script>` & `<link>` tags which are wrongly hitting to https://angular4AppDomain.com/, instead hit to [https://angular4AppDomain.com/8080/](https://angular4AppDomain.com/PORT/)?

Comment: Are you using webpack / angular-cli / bundling tool?

Comment: @OmriLuzon I believe we're using typings

Comment: I'm asking because there isn't enough information to answer that question. Error 404 is usually caused by misnamed / misplaced directories. Please explain about your deployment process.

Comment: @OmriLuzon We've taken [this template](https://github.com/gopinav/Angular-2-Tutorials), I'll share the deployment details in the question itself.

Comment: Do you set properly `<base href=""` attribute?

Comment: @VadimB Yup, `<base href="/">` seems to be set

Comment: And you do not use virtual path in accessing website? I mean smth like: `http://example.com/someapp/index.html` ?

Comment: @VadimB No, we're accessing the app from the main path only

Comment: @OmriLuzon I have shared the deployment process in the question itself

Comment: I don't the problem has something to do with `pm2` because express is already responding to you with 404, Do you have all your components in a separate directory, and is there something special about it compared to other imported `.ts` files?

Comment: @OmriLuzon Nothing, we just used the [template](https://github.com/gopinav/Angular-2-Tutorials) and edited as per our needs

Comment: @VadimB Yes, we're using virtual path. However, instead of hitting [http://example.com/someapp/index.html](http://example.com/someapp/index.html), we're hitting [http://example.com/PORT/index.html](http://example.com/PORT/index.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a quick demo:

1. `git clone` this sample repo which uses angular-cli https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample
2. `cd` into the folder.
3. `ng build --base-href /PORT/`
4. install node module `liter-server` globally and run `lite-server` command from the root of the project
5. open the below link and u can see that it works fine with the path in the url.
6. http://localhost:3000/PORT/index.html